# Facebook Class Schedule App

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-apps

I am looking for a Facebook app where one can add schedules. I have a created a Fan Page for a dance school and they want to show their weekly classes, and I can't seem to find anything decent, and if it is I need to subscribe to a whole lot of other sites for it to work (and most are not free).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty easy, you're doing a lot more work than you need to. Just create a Google Calendar and then create a HTTPS page with it embedded inside it then turn it into an app via FB dev side and add it to the fan page....

Comment: This is what I have done at the moment. But this restricts me to having admins that use Google Calendar, and I'm looking for a way to make it more generic. Don't get me wrong, I prefer the Google Calendar way, but not all admins have it :P

Answer (score -2):

do you need some kind of allication like this

http://www.tanvtech.com/Products/SchoolStudentScheduler.aspx

Comment: The asker is looking for Facebook apps.